# Rails - Handle multiple dynamic fields with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a model `foo` in my rails app, and in the index page all the `foos` are listed in a table. Each `foo` has 2 integer properties: quarto and jesolo.

[image]

I'm giving different ids to the html number fields, in the following way:

**foo #1**

1st field: foo1_quarto

2st field: foo1_jesolo

**foo #2**

1st field: foo2_quarto

2st field: foo2_jesolo

ecc...

At the moment I'm using the following ajax code (written in coffee script) to make the user input on `foo1_quarto` being reflected also in `foo1_jesolo`:

```
$("#foo1_quarto").keyup ->
    a = parseInt document.getElementById("foo_quarto").value
    $("#foo1_jesolo").val a
```

But now I need to serialize this. I don't know in advance how many food there will be, and **I'd like to have a piece of ajax code that covers all of them**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand your english, but couldn't you collect all the inputs and serialize them like so ?

```
$("input").serialize ->
```

So in an AJAX call it would be :

```
$.ajax '/',
    type: 'POST'
    data: $("#my_form input").serialize ->
    dataType: 'script' error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        $('body').append "AJAX Error: #{textStatus}"
    success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        $('body').append "Successful AJAX call: #{data}"
```

Also, I'd personally stray away from using unique ID's for your `keyup` method. In this way, you wouldn't have to write the same thing for every single item.

Instead I would make each one share a common class `.foo_input` and/or `.other_foo`, and write it like so :

```
$(".foo_input").keyup ->
    $(this).sibling(".other_foo").val $(this).value
```

But ideally, you would use one class and use jQuery selectors to get to it. Not sure how your HTML is set up.

Comment: Following your suggetion I used one class and jQuery selectors to get to it. Thanks!